# why in line 18 the error: AttributeError: 'FibCounter' object has no attribute 'Fibcounter' occurs

Tags: python

```
class FibCounter:

    def __int__(self):
        self.Fibcounter = 0

    def getCount(self):
        return self.Fibcounter

    def resetCount(self):
        self.Fibcounter = 0
        return self.Fibcounter

    def fib(self,n):
        self.Fibcounter = self.Fibcounter + 1
        if n<3:
            return 1
        else:
            return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)

def main():
    n = eval(input("Enter the value of n (n represents the nth Fibonacci number):" ))
    Fibonacci = FibCounter()
    Fibonacci.fib(n)
    print("The number of time fib function is called is:",Fibonacci.getCount())
    Fibonacci.resetCount()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Comment: This appears to be off-topic because it was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.

Comment: `getCount()` is pointless as you can directly access the attribute (and should do so in Python, unlike in Java). And `resetCount()` should not return `self.Fibcounter` as it is pointless to do so; just omit the `return` directive in order to (implicitly) return `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an `i`:

```
def __int__(self):
```

You want

```
def __init__(self):
```

which is why `Fibcounter` isn't set; your `__int__` function is never called.

(Note though that `Fibcounter` isn't a great name for a variable in a `FibCounter` class, and so you might want to change it.)

After that, there are some other issues to fix (`fib` won't be able to call itself, e.g.)

Comment: Would you please explain why fib won't be able to call itself? Thank you!

Comment: @user3478368: try it.  You need to refer to the method via `self.fib`.